# How to include container into another container dynamically in Hippo CMS, by drag'n'dropping them from catalog toolbar?

Tags: drag-and-drop, components, containers, catalog, hippocms

I'm using Hippo CMS 10. Through console, in **hst:catalog** I've created **hst:containeritemcomponent** with *hst:xtype, hst:referencecomponent, hst:iconpath, hst:label*. 

hst:referencecomponent references to **hst:containercomponentfolder** at *hst:workspace/hst:containers*/, which contain **hst:containercomponent** with **hst:xtype** set to **HST.Span**

I need container, that can contain (dynamically) variable amount of another different containers. For example, I want to be able to create this structure by  drag'n'dropping components from catalog toolbar:

```
<!-- this must be main container, already positioned in page -->
<div class="content">

    <!-- this should appear when I drag'n'drop component from toolbar -->
    <!-- at the same time, it must be container for other components itself -->
    <div class="row">...</div>

    <!-- this also comes from drag'n'dropped component from toolbar -->
    <!-- and also container for other components -->
    <div class="home banner">...</div>

    <!-- any amount of containers -->
    ...
    ...
</div>
```

By this way, I should be able to create some page structure dynamically. Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve it? If no, how to bypass it, what's the idea?
HippoCMS's site is very poor for such kind of examples, and there is no information about hippocms except for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know the problem: please have a look at this documentation that explains the configuration:

http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/hst-configuration-model/containers-configuration.html

This documentation page explains how to customize the HTML rendered by the containers:
http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/template-composer/how-to-prevent-additional-html-elements-for-containers.html

The problems I see:

- you are missing an *hst:include* in your template. Such as for example:

  `<hst:include ref="mycontainer" />`
- you've created the **hst:containeritemcomponent** in the **hst:catalog** but to be editable containers must also be created in the **hst:workspace**.
- in your HST configuration you must also configure a reference to the container you have in the workspace. Such as this example:
  [image: Sample configuration]

The catalog is a palette of components. The components you see in the toolbar can only be drag&dropped on a template which have **containers** to handle those components. The **xtype** defines the kind of container that will handle the component(s) you drag&drop (table, , etc.). So you can do stuff like stacking.

You cannot include a container into another container dynamically.

Comment: I have rephrased my question a little bit, with some example. Can you please read it again?

Comment: From your last sentence I may conclude that it's not possible to do what I want (include a container into another container dynamically by just drag'n'dropping components from catalog toolbar). Am I right?

Comment: You are right: you cannot drag'n'drop a container into another container. That being said, I cannot think of any use-case that would require to include a container into another container. I've seen quite a few implementations and what is done is that a container includes multiple components. So maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve, we'll find another solution that will fit the constraints. You can also try the Hippo Google group as there are more people following it.